# How to filter an object array which coming from store(via selector)

Tags: angular, redux, state, ngrx, store

I want to filter an array which coming from state and return an observable boolean. It is my selector

```
export const customArray = createSelector(
  arrayCustomizations,
  (entities: Dictionary<Customizations>, props: { id: string }) => {
    const customizations = entities[props.id];
    return customizations.allCustoms;
  },
);
```

This returns an object array. I want to get all object that have 'name' property like object.name !== null and assign it to this
`buttonDisabled$=`
If i subscribe this selector, i can filter and get what i want but it is not an observable value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` method of `rxjs` for this purpose. This will give you observable value.

Use like this.

```
export const customArray = createSelector(
  arrayCustomizations,
  (entities: Dictionary<Customizations>, props: { id: string }) => {
    const customizations = entities[props.id];
    return customizations.allCustoms;
  },
).pipe(
  filter(object => object.name !== null)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it returns 'undefined'. I tried this first,

Answer (score 0):

It is performant and efficient if manipulate data in the selector. `createSelector` is memoized and track the value changes and does not propagate value to the listener if the value does not change.

```
export const customArray = createSelector(
  arrayCustomizations,
  (entities: Dictionary<Customizations>, props: { id: string }) => {
    const customizations = entities[props.id];
    return customizations.allCustoms.filer(o => o.name != null);
  },
);
```

based on the comment below alternative could be

in selector.ts

```
export const customArray = createSelector(
  arrayCustomizations,
  (entities: Dictionary<Customizations>, props: { id: string }) => {
    const customizations = entities[props.id];
    return customizations.allCustoms;
  },
);
```

in component.ts

```
this.result$ = this.store.pipe(select(customArray, { id: '123' })).pipe(
 map(result => result.filter(a => a.name != null))
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in the component? Because this selector is used by others.When i do this same ting in the component, i get undefined.

Comment: Couple of other options 

- pass more props other than id to fine tune the results. 

- pipe the result and use filter operator on the component level

Comment: Check out the map operator then filter the result inside